# Retrieve current date , sqlite android

Tags: android

i'm trying to retrieve the current date via unix time like this:

```
   long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    Date d = new Date(unixTime);
    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
    tmp.append(d.getYear());
    tmp.append(" - ");
    tmp.append(d.getMonth());
    tmp.append(" - ");
    tmp.append(d.getDay());`
```

When i later print this out via `tmp.getString()` i get the following date 70 - 0 - 4 , is there something im missing ?

//Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods you are using are deprecated. You better use the `GregorianCalendar` class:

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar=new GregorianCalendar();            
StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
tmp.append(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
tmp.append(" - ");
tmp.append(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
tmp.append(" - ");
tmp.append(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
```

Comment: thx but i have a minor problem , GregorianCalendar.MONTH gives me the wrong value by a month, is there any quick fix to this ?

Comment: i just incremented it by 1 but i dunno if its a good fix tbh, it could be that GregorianCalendar.MONTH counts january as 0 ? .

Comment: Yes... it's a zero-indexed result.

Comment: Also, please note: there is a constant for each month, i.e. for January it will be **GregorianCalendar.JANUARY** (==0). It is highly recommended to use these constants instead of direct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Date takes milliseconds since epoch. So just don't divide unixTime by 1000.